# Displaying value in a thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I built my thymeleaf template to display some values from database in specific fields . I had two classes "Iden" and "Target" joined , each "iden" had many "target".  I m trying to display those values interconnecting the two classes i got an error in my thymeleaf template ("Property or field 'ref' cannot be found on null"). Any one could help to find what happens.

```
<td th:text="${p.iden.ref}"></td>
```

this is the code of iden class :

```js
package com.example.dot.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Entity
@Table(name = "iden")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
       generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id_iden")

public class Iden implements Serializable {
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Long id_iden;
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") 
 @Column(name = "dte_deb_inter", columnDefinition="DATE")
 private Date dte_deb_inter;
 private String cse_deb_inter;
 private String ref ;
 private String dir_gen;
 private String dir_chg;
 
 
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "iden", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<Target> targets;
 
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_ORD")
 public Ordre ordre;

 public List<Target> getTargets() {
  return targets;
 }

 public void setTargets(List<Target> targets) {
  this.targets = targets;
 }

 public Iden() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public Iden(Date dte_deb_inter,  String cse_deb_inter, 
   String ref,String dir_gen,String dir_chg ,Ordre ordre) {
  super();
  this.dte_deb_inter = dte_deb_inter;
  
  this.cse_deb_inter = cse_deb_inter;
  
  this.dir_chg =dir_chg;
  this.dir_gen =dir_gen;
  this.ref =ref;
  this.ordre = ordre;
 }

 public Long getId_iden() {
  return id_iden;
 }

 public void setId_iden(Long id_iden) {
  this.id_iden = id_iden;
 }

 public Date getDte_deb_inter() {
  return dte_deb_inter;
 }

 public void setDte_deb_inter(Date dte_deb_inter) {
  this.dte_deb_inter = dte_deb_inter;
 }

 

 public String getCse_deb_inter() {
  return cse_deb_inter;
 }

 public void setCse_deb_inter(String cse_deb_inter) {
  this.cse_deb_inter = cse_deb_inter;
 }

 

 public Ordre getOrdre() {
  return ordre;
 }

 public void setOrdre(Ordre ordre) {
  this.ordre = ordre;
 }

 
 public String getRef() {
  return ref;
 }

 public void setRef(String ref) {
  this.ref = ref;
 }

 public String getDir_gen() {
  return dir_gen;
 }

 public void setDir_gen(String dir_gen) {
  this.dir_gen = dir_gen;
 }

 public String getDir_chg() {
  return dir_chg;
 }

 public void setDir_chg(String dir_chg) {
  this.dir_chg = dir_chg;
 }

 

}
```

this is the code of target class :

```js
package com.example.dot.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Entity
@Table(name = "target")

@JsonIdentityInfo(
       generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id_trg")
public class Target implements Serializable{

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Long id_trg;
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") 
 @Column(name = "dte_fin_inter", columnDefinition="DATE")
 private Date dte_fin_inter;
    private String cse_fin_inter;
 private String acti ;
 private Integer flag_status;
 private String name ;
 private String type ;
 private Long number ;
 private String st;
 private String ope;
 private String por ;
 
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_IDEN")
 public Iden iden;
 
 public Target() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 
 
 
 
 public Target(Date dte_fin_inter, String cse_fin_inter, String acti, Integer flag_status, String name, String type,
   Long number, String st, String por,String ope, Iden iden) {
  super();
  this.ope = ope;
  this.dte_fin_inter = dte_fin_inter;
  this.cse_fin_inter = cse_fin_inter;
  this.acti = acti;
  this.flag_status = flag_status;
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.number = number;
  this.st = st;
  this.por = por;
  this.iden = iden;
 }





 public Long getId_trg() {
  return id_trg;
 }

 public void setId_trg(Long id_trg) {
  this.id_trg = id_trg;
 }

 public Date getDte_fin_inter() {
  return dte_fin_inter;
 }

 public void setDte_fin_inter(Date dte_fin_inter) {
  this.dte_fin_inter = dte_fin_inter;
 }

 public String getCse_fin_inter() {
  return cse_fin_inter;
 }

 public void setCse_fin_inter(String cse_fin_inter) {
  this.cse_fin_inter = cse_fin_inter;
 }

 public String getActi() {
  return acti;
 }

 public void setActi(String acti) {
  this.acti = acti;
 }

 public Integer getFlag_status() {
  return flag_status;
 }

 public void setFlag_status(Integer flag_status) {
  this.flag_status = flag_status;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getType() {
  return type;
 }

 public void setType(String type) {
  this.type = type;
 }

 public Long getNumber() {
  return number;
 }

 public void setNumber(Long number) {
  this.number = number;
 }

 public String getSt() {
  return st;
 }

 public void setSt(String st) {
  this.st = st;
 }

 public String getpor() {
  return por;
 }

 public void setpor(String por) {
  this.por = por;
 }

 public Iden getIden() {
  return iden;
 }

 public void setIden(Iden iden) {
  this.iden = iden;
 }





 public String getOpe() {
  return ope;
 }





 public void setOpe(String ope) {
  this.ope = ope;
 }


  
}
```

this is the controller code to get the list of targets :

```js
@Controller
public class TargetController {

 @Autowired
Targetrepository trgrepo;
 
 
 
 
 @RequestMapping("/alltarget")
 public String formall(Model model) {
  List<Target> listTarget =trgrepo.findAll();
 model.addAttribute("list",listTarget);
  return "allIdentifiant";
 }
 
 
 
}
```

and Finally the thymeleaf template :

```html
 <tbody>
    <tr th:each="p:${list}">
    
     <td th:text="${p.cse_fin_inter}"></td>
    
     
     <td><span th:text="${p.iden.ref}" ></span> </td>
         
     
     <td th:text="${p.acti}"></td>
     <td><span th:text="${p.por}" ></span></td>
     <td><span th:text="${p.ope}"></span></td>
     
     <td th:text="${#dates.format(p.dte_fin_inter, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></td>
     
     <td><span th:text="${p.st}"></span></td>
     <td><span th:text="${p.number}"></span></td>
     <td><span th:text="${p.name}"></span></td>
     <td>
      
     </td>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self explainatory in this case. `Property or field 'X' cannot be found on null` means thymeleaf tried to call a getter method on a null object. In your case, `p.iden.ref`, it means iden was null.

The possible solutions you've are:

- Make sure in the controller that your iden attribute is not null in any of your targets.
- Check that you won't try to access iden if it is null, in the following way:

  ```
  <span th:if="${p.iden != null}" th:text="${p.iden.ref}" ></span>
  ```